# Numeric indicator inside a RadRadialGauge elemnet

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

how can i put a Numeric indicator inside a RadRadialGauge?

```
  <RadRadialGauge title="Exp" height="150" width="150">
    <TitleStyle tkRadialGaugeTitleStyle textColor="gray" textSize="12" verticalOffset="90"></TitleStyle>
    <RadialScale tkRadialGaugeScales startAngle="270" sweepAngle="360" minimum="0" maximum="100">

        <ScaleStyle tkRadialScaleStyle ticksVisible="false" labelsVisible="false" lineThickness="0"></ScaleStyle>

        <RadialBarIndicator tkRadialScaleIndicators minimum="0" maximum="100" location="0.75">
            <BarIndicatorStyle tkRadialBarIndicatorStyle fillColor="rgba(192,192,192,0.8)" barWidth="0.1"></BarIndicatorStyle>
        </RadialBarIndicator>

        <RadialBarIndicator tkRadialScaleIndicators minimum="0" maximum="30" location="0.75" isAnimated="true">
            <BarIndicatorStyle tkRadialBarIndicatorStyle cap="Round" fillColor="rgba(67,183,120,0.9)" barWidth="0.1"></BarIndicatorStyle>
        </RadialBarIndicator>




    </RadialScale>
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: Consider adding a description with what you are trying to achieve, what you tried so far, and what the end result should look like.

Comment: i want a radial gauge with inside (in the center of the circle formed by the element) a number that rapresent a value, the same indicated by the radial gauge element. so my question is : Can i modify the code that i post or there is an other way to do it? i'm new with nativescript and i don't know how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved: i use title to insert the value

`<RadRadialGauge title ="{{value}}%"height="150" width="150" >

    <TitleStyle tkRadialGaugeTitleStyle textColor="gray" textSize="30" 
          textAlignment="center" verticalOffset="0" horizontalOffset="0"></TitleStyle>`